# Binding error on a property that does not have any binding set

Tags: c#, xaml

Visual Studio is displaying the following error in its output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
    BindingExpression path error:
    'Text' property not found on 'object' ''PropertyAppraisalWorkflowViewModel' (HashCode=35281714)'. BindingExpression:Path=Text;
DataItem='PropertyAppraisalWorkflowViewModel' (HashCode=35281714);
target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='cmbWorkflowView');
target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

The odd part is that I do not have the property "Text" bound (or even being used) for the cmbWorkflowView control.

Here is a truncated snippet of the XAML that the error is saying has the problem:

```
    <Grid Name="grdWorkflow">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultComboBox}" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                  Name="cmbWorkflowView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewOptions}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedView}"
                  props:ComboBoxProperties.SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectWorkflowView}" />
    </Grid>
```

As you can see, the ComboBox in question isn't even using the Text field let alone binding it. What is causing the error? (See below. I solved the problem, but since I could not find anything anywhere else that had this same solution to this problem, I decided to post the solution here in case it could help someone else out.)

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution was the style. In the code, the style is separated by more XAML. I had forgotten that the ComboBox had a style associated with it. When I followed the style to its source, I found the following. (This is truncated for readability, the actual style is more involved.)

```
    <Style x:Key="DefaultComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource DefaultControlHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Text}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableFieldBrush}" />
    </Style>
```

The style had bound the "Text" property. Once I removed Setter for the "Text" property, the error disappeared.

```
    <Style x:Key="DefaultComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource DefaultControlHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableFieldBrush}" />
    </Style>
```